# certain 3D modeled objects from blender are invisible from the one side in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, blender

I imported my low-poly 3D models that I built, posed and textured in blender and exported as FBX files into unity, and I believe I might have done something wrong with the texturing (I am new to this) because the sails of the ship are invisible and non-interactive from the front but visible from the back. It also does this with various other objects from other set pieces, but I'm struggling to find the overlapping problem as they are not based off the same shapes and have different materials. Any solutions, suggestions or advice would be appreciated. [the sail that should be visible on the mast that I was describing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Z1wi.png)

I tried googling the problem and found similar forum questions but nothing really specific to my problem, I also tried working with the materials of the objects directly in unity but they're greyed out and completely non-interactive. I can drag and drop pre-existing materials onto them but I don't quite know how to make a material in unity from scratch.

Comment: It seems like you only render one side of the faces, you might want to try this on the mast [Double sided faces](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10711/double-sided-faces)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's likely that your problem is with the normal's orientation.

To fix that, you can open your model in Blender, for example, then, check the "Face Orientation" box.

[image]

If there are red faces, select them then go to "Mesh/Normals/Flip"

[image]

Then you're ready to export you model to Unity.

This practice is the best one, since you're not going to add more faces, nor rendering both faces, what whould duplicate the processing consumption for that model.

I hope I help you!

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways I would do this (and I'm not saying this is best practice or anything)

A: Create a new face on the model, where the normal faces the other way

1. Select your sail in blender
2. Tab to enter edit mode
3. Select all (normal shortcut [A])
4. [Shift + D] to duplicate
5. [Ctrl + Shift + N] to flip normals
6. Continue to export as .fbx and see if that worked

B: Make / Find a shader (as this is not to do with materials)
After a quick search I found this: https://youtu.be/kbBDZYi2IMA

Hope this helps

Comment: Without going into too much depth, this seems like the answer.  Either flip the faces in Blender, or create a double sided shader.

Comment: This has helped me get somewhere, not quite to where I need to be but I'm no longer stuck here, thank you.